# Is it possible to use `_getattr__`-generated methods in a subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class whose methods may or may not be auto-generated. I want to be able to call these methods from a subclass, but can't figure out how to do that.

Consider this code:

```
class Upgrader:
    max = 99

    def _upgrade_no_op(self, db):
        if self.version < Upgrader.max:
            self.version += 1

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(key)    
        except AttributeError:
            if key.startswith("upgrade_v"):    
                nr = int(key[9:])
                if 0 <= nr < self.max:                   
                    return self._upgrade_no_op
            raise

class Foo(Upgrader):
    version = 1
    def upgrade_v2(self):
        # None of these work:

        # Upgrade.upgrade_v2(self)
        # super().upgrade_v2()
        # super(Foo,self).upgrade_v2()
        # x = Upgrade.__getattribute__(self, "upgrade_v2");  # bound to Foo.upgrade_v2
        breakpoint()

Foo().upgrade_v2()
```

In my real code there are one or two other classes between `Foo` and `Upgrader`, but you get the idea.

Is there a way to do this, preferably without writing my own version of `super()`?

Comment: Just call the method normally. Inheritance of the `__getattribute__()` method should make it apply to the subclass. `self.upgrade_v2()`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `__getattribute__` the way you are (unconditionally trying to see if it can find the method on a higher up class)? Typically, if you want resolvable lookups to occur without you intervening, you'd just use `__getattr__` (which is only invoked when the attribute can't be found, much like your `try:`/`return super().__getattribute__(key)`/`except AttributeError:` is trying to do). Defining `__getattribute__` is *way* more intrusive (it gets invoked for every lookup, including simple attributes, where `super()` doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Barmar: They're calling it *from* `upgrade_v2` in the subclass, so if they use `self.upgrade_v2()` it's instant unbounded recursion; `self.upgrade_v2()` goes through `Upgrader.__getattribute__` which then gets the `Foo.upgrade_v2`, which is then called, which then calls `self.upgrade_v2()`, and so on, until it dies with a stack of `upgrade_v2` calls (the `__getattribute__` call might end the stack, but it won't be seen within it, because it's always fully resolved before the next real call to `Foo.upgrade_v2` occurs.

Comment: This seems a little bit like an XY problem. What *problem* are you trying to solve by supporting arbitrarily named attributes that all essentially resolve to the same method?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems:

1. `return super().__getattribute__(key)` looks for `__getattribute__` on a superclass (typically `object`), but the actual lookup of `key` is a plain lookup, it's not bypassing classes in the MRO, it's just restarting the lookup from *first* class in the MRO (the one that `self` is actually an instance of). `super()` is magic *once*; it'll skip past earlier classes in the MRO to perform the lookup that one time, then it's done. This is what you want when the attribute exists and you're being called from outside the class's methods (`Foo().update_v2()`'s *initial* call is going through `Updater.__getattribute__` to find `Foo.update_v2` in the first place), but when `Foo.update_v2` tries to invoke a "maybe doesn't exist" parent version of `update_v2`, even when you manage to invoke the parent `__getattribute__` (e.g. by directly invoking `Upgrader.__getattribute__(self, "upgrade_v2")()`), it's just going to give you `Foo.update_v2` again, leading to infinite recursion.
2. `super()` bypasses a lot of the dynamic lookup machinery; it will find only things with the appropriate name attached to each class after the one invoking it in the MRO, but it won't try invoking `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` on each of those classes as it goes (that would slow things down dramatically, and complicate the code significantly). It's already generally a bad idea to rely on `__getattribute__` to provide what amounts to core class functionality; having it dynamically intercept *all* lookups to insert things into the middle of inheritance chains *during lookup* is at best some truly intense code smell.

   99.99%+ of the time, you don't want dynamic lookup handling at all, and in the rare cases you do, you almost always want `__getattr__` (which is only invoked when the name can't be found in any other way), not `__getattribute__` (which is invoked unconditionally).

   Neither special method works with `super()`-triggered lookups the way you want though, so if you truly *needed* something like this, you'd be stuck re-implementing what `super()` is doing manually, but adding in dynamic lookup special method support as well (working over the instance's MRO manually, looking for what you want from each class, then if it lacks it, manually invoking `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__` to see if it can generate it, then moving on to the next class if that fails too). This is *insane*; do not try to do it.

I strongly suspect you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here. What you're trying to do is inherently brittle, and only makes *any* kind of sense in a complicated inheritance hierarchy where `super().upgrade_v2()` in `Foo.upgrade_v2` might actually find a useful function in some class that is inherited along with `Foo` by some hypothetical third class that involves a diamond inheritance pattern leading back to `Upgrader`. That's already complicated enough, and now you're adding `__getattribute__` (which slows *every* use of the class instances, and has a ton of pitfalls of its own even without inheritance of any kind); it's a bad idea.

If, as in this case, you have a smallish fixed set of methods that should exist, just generate them up front, and avoid `__getattribute__` entirely:

```
class Upgrader:
    max = 99

    def _upgrade_no_op(self):
        if self.version < Upgrader.max:
            self.version += 1

# Dynamically bind _upgrade_no_op to each name we intend to support on Upgrader
for i in range(Upgrader.max):
    setattr(Upgrader, f'upgrade_v{i}', Upgrader._upgrade_no_op)

class Foo(Upgrader):
    version = 1
    def upgrade_v2(self):
        # Upgrade.upgrade_v2(self)
        super().upgrade_v2()  # Works just fine

f = Foo()
print(f.version)  # See original version of 1 here
f.upgrade_v2()
print(f.version)  # See updated version of 2 here
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBTsMwEETv/oqRemgiqkgtpyJ6Q/wAQhwr06wTQ@q1bKdQIb49OG3jppHYW5y3M7Njj6Fmc991u0Z6j1dbOVmSexCIs5ff2GC9FqevkhS27RnYGt6yzTw1Kj@z/WiF/qU4kPOaDR6TXhGlrlw/N@DdBkshZng6GrnXO9k0R7xrU078EBgkdzUiRfgiaBMoUvHZt9ayC4hig6dQ7KAjAydNRdk4yyW0pyBDcOnXAmo@OB5@9O98cb3gNkouxLmxZ@a0flEdruqPGopLqqtpabPBopgyCYnHkcvyMZD3i2/sPj0@Wh@gtCEBIVR07SPlwrrYTpY6Pi28EIGdrrSRTYrJCkvU5EioG4d/FVpbykDlWGB1Eui6Pw)

You code will work, run dramatically faster (no Python level function calls involved in *every* attribute and method lookup), and it won't drive maintainers insane trying to figure out what you're doing.